# Servlet POST request with basic authentification

Tags: java, servlets, basic-authentication

i'm trying to send a POST request to an URL which needs basic authentification, i've looked for a solution here and there, but my servlet still doesn't get a result, here is my code, i hope you could help me to solve this because i'm in a real struggle.

```
       //Basic Auth + envoi réponse
       //backUrl=http://....../ws   
        String webPage = backUrl ;
        String name = "CLT_NAGT";
        String password = "azerty@1234567";

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        //Connexion

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.connect();

        //Envoi du JSON 

        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        outputWriter.write(Json);//Json is a json.toString() object
        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();
```

in my browser i got a blank page and my eclipse doesn't throw an exception or any errors. how can i fix this ?

Comment: Where are you reading the response?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Are talking about the inputstreamreader ?

Comment: If you are not getting any response in browser, then what are you expecting in client side code ? You need to share server side implementation especially your servlet code, which you are trying to invoke

Comment: i just need to send the json.toString() to the specified URL

Comment: this is my servlet:

Comment: Your code only sends data. Do you expect to get a response?

Comment: I don't care what are you sending right now. question is whether your server side implementation is correct ? did you tried any client to check whether server has correct implementation ?

Comment: @Onizuka You need to understand first that, whatever you have shared is client side implementation and you won't get any magical response until your server sends.

Comment: it was tested by SoapUI and it does not return a response, the logs on the specified URL doesn't show nothing

Comment: i mean it works with SoapUI but not with my servlet

Comment: if it doesn't return any response, then what are you expecting I stii don't get it.

Comment: @Kayaman:no, i don't expect to get an answer,i just verify the logs on client side and there is nothing even a connection

Comment: @Ravi: in logs, i can find the other data sent from another applications, the connection date even the failure of transmission, in my case , i can't even find that a connection was detected !

Answer (score 0):

this is my servlet (the server side)

```
    public class ServletAO extends HttpServlet {

    /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setContentType("application/json");

    //récupération du resultat de l'exécution de l'AO
    PA865AccessObject ao = (PA865AccessObject) req.getAttribute("ao");
    String aoResp = ao.getMessage();
    String rep="";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String reportDate = df.format(today);
    //récupération des paramètres de la requete
       //       String nomPrenom = req.getParameter("nomPrenom");
    String adrLigne1 = req.getParameter("adresse1");
    String adrLigne2 = req.getParameter("adresse2");
    String adrLigne3 = req.getParameter("adresse3");
    String adrLigne4 = req.getParameter("adrLigne4");
    String adrLigne5 = req.getParameter("adrLigne5");
    String codePostal = req.getParameter("codepostal");
    String ville = req.getParameter("ville");
    String pays = req.getParameter("pays");
    String numContrat = req.getParameter("numContrat");
    String numAbonne = req.getParameter("numAbonne");
    String idRequest = req.getParameter("idRequest");
    String backUrl = req.getParameter("backurl");


    if(aoResp.indexOf("MISE A JOUR EFFECTUEE")>-1)
    {
        rep="2-Taken";
    }
    else 
    {
        rep="4-Dropped";
    }

    //Fichier JSON


    JSONObject technical= new JSONObject();
    try {
        technical.put("topic", "fr-sicl-Address_Contact_Change_Request-v1");
        technical.put("organization", "fr");
        technical.put("sa","SICLIENT");
        technical.put("nature", "business");
        technical.put("sk", "0");
        technical.put("version", "1");
        technical.put("source_event_id", "ID");
        technical.put("event_id", "IDCalcule");
        technical.put("event_date_time", reportDate);
        technical.put("emission_date_time", reportDate);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println(technical.toString());



    JSONObject payload= new JSONObject();
    try {
        payload.put("distrib_customer_ids", numAbonne);
        payload.put("party_customer_id", "A verifier");
        payload.put("contract_id",numContrat);
        payload.put("correlation_id", idRequest);
        payload.put("request_id", idRequest);
        payload.put("request_issued_date_time", reportDate);
        payload.put("request_event_type", rep);
        payload.put("request_event_reason", "PA865");
        payload.put("source_system", "CIARD");
        payload.put("party_row_id", "A verifier");
        payload.put("replaced_address_date_time", reportDate);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println(payload.toString());




    JSONObject newAdress = new JSONObject();

    try {
        newAdress.put("recipient_line1", adrLigne1);
        newAdress.put("line2", adrLigne2);
        newAdress.put("line3",adrLigne3);
        newAdress.put("street_line4", adrLigne4);
        newAdress.put("line5", adrLigne5);
        newAdress.put("zip_locality_line6", "");
        newAdress.put("country_label_line7", "");
        newAdress.put("zip_postal_code", codePostal);
        newAdress.put("locality", ville);
        newAdress.put("country", pays);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(newAdress.toString());

    String Json = 
   technical.toString()+payload.toString()+newAdress.toString();


   //Basic Auth + envoi réponse

        String webPage = backUrl ;
        String name = "CLT_NAGT";
        String password = "azerty@1234567";

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        //Connexion

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = 
        (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + 
      authStringEnc);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
      "application/json");
        urlConnection.connect();

        //Envoi du JSON 

        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        outputWriter.write("");
        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();

        //resp.flushBuffer();   

     }



     }
```

Comment: This section belongs to answers not for partial post. Also, we can't look at your servlet code. You need to tell us whether you are getting any response from your servlet. You need to debug this part, check server log, try any existing client like postman and validate your server side implementation